# Delete the temporary object from object.new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, show, destroy

In the show action, there is logic that requires me to define:

```
@object.nested_object.new (or @object.nested_object.build or @object.nested_object.create)
```

However, when it's time to show a list of the nested_objects using something like:

```
@object.nested_objects.each do |nested_objects|
  #display
end
```

There is an extra line item for the temporary nested object created with @object.nested_object.new.

Is there a way to forcefully remove that temporary object before I display the list of the actual nested_objects?

Or is there another way of accomplishing the following:

```
-creating a temporary nested_object for logic tests
-showing a list of nested_objects
```

I've tried stuff like:

```
temp_nested_object = @object.nested_object.new
temp_nested_object.delete
```

but wasn't successful.

Thanks for your time!

UPDATE:
I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
<% if can? :create, @project.tasks.build %>
```

From here:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources
I've tried to find other ways of accomplishing this:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/608
but seems like I need to workaround it in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should not `create` a temporary object.

if you follow the previous advice, simply do:

```
@object.nested_objects.select(&:persisted?).each do |nested_objects|
  #display
end
```

This will filter objects from your db (no need to delete a temporary object, it will disappear at the end of the request).

Comment: I really like the persisted? method.  I definitely don't want to create a temporary object, but can't find a way around it.  I'm trying to accomplish this:<% if can? :create, @project.tasks.build %> from the documentation: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources  If you know a better way of accomplishing this, then I'd definitely love to hear it.  Thanks again for your valuable input!

Comment: when you `build` a temporary object, it is not persisted. So it's fine. Consider upvoting if you like the idea

Comment: Do you think there's a way of getting around using build?

Comment: I don't understand your question. if you use `build` the resulting object will respond `false` to `persisted?` isn't it what you want?

Comment: Yes, persisted? is exactly what I want.  But it's a by-product of using build earlier due to CanCan.  I was wondering if you knew of a way to use CanCan, without using build so I can avoid having to use persisted?  Trying to nib the issue at the bud sort of thing.  Just wondering.  Thanks!  I'm going to accept your answer now.

Comment: could you ask another detailed question with this point explained please?

Comment: I was just wondering...not a big deal.  I'm happy with this overall solution.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to just remove it from the collection with:

```
# Remove last object in collection
@object.nested_objects.pop
```